single phase into vfd
I have a three phase in three phase out vfd which is rated for 230V. I would like to use it to power a three phase motor. The manufacturer of the drive states it will run from a single phase input, however it puts extra stress on the rectifier circuit of the vfd. If I put a motor run capacitor between L1 and the third phase of the drive would that help to balance the input? I know its not perfect but would it be better than just single phase?

How much current can it take? How much current will you need? If manufacturer says it’s ok to use single phase input and your current is less the max specified, you shouldn’t need to do anything.


"...however it puts extra stress on the rectifier circuit of the vfd."

No it doesn't. Post a link that says otherwise. The input rectifiers are rated to handle the current.
A few things to consider: The input current will be higher while running single phase. Depending on the drive, this either means you will have to de-rate the output capacity by (58%?). Or, the input conductors have to increase in size to handle the higher current. Also, you may have to go through the drive settings and disable "input phase loss" fault detection. Again, this will depend on the specific drive.

the drive is made by ls electric. They say on their website in the faq's "Dear Customer, Basically, we do not recommend this. This kind of insecure input can make DC Voltage ripple increase and cause power module damage like capacitor burst. So we can not guarantee the normal operation and product quality. Thank you."

@SimonMclennan OK. That's implying you would want to derate the drive for reliable operation. For example, if you have a 2HP drive, you would want to run something like a1HP motor at most. If the input capacitors have a ripple limit, that can analytically be deduced from the normal 3ph operation (assuming no PFC). But that would be a different question. Actually, that would be a really good question - "Derating 1ph input current from acceptable 3ph operation"
